# Can you assign a task to a contact using exchange 2010 EWS Managed API 2.0?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm struggling to find a way to assign a Task that I'm creating using the EWS Managed API 2.0  to an existing contact. Is there a way to do this using the API?

For appointments, you can add an Atendee to the RequiredAtendees collection. Is there something similar to this for Tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, EWS does not support assigning tasks. You can access a user's mailbox either as a delegate or via impersonation and create Tasks in their Task folder, but you can't create one in your mailbox and assign to someone else.

Comment: Not really. You might reverse-engineer the appropriate MAPI properties to make it sort of work, but you won't get all the other features that go with Task assignment (notification mails, etc).

Comment: I'm trying to use the web service and see if I manage to do something regarding this. Will keep posted. Thanks anyways